# WP Jetpack publicize insert default text(s)

Tags: php, wordpress, jetpack

How can I place a default text (hashtag) in the Custom Message?

The textarea is (located in line 643) under `jetpack/modules/publicize/ui.php`

I tried to put the text in front of `$title` in various ways, like:

`<?php echo "#myhashtag $title"; ?>`

or

`<?php echo '#myhashtag '.$title; ?>`

but it just echoes the text, not the `$title`.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is [any of this filters](http://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/customizing-publicize-sharing-behavior/#altering-the-default-messages) useful?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the approach of [this Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/publicize-with-hashtags/) i made ([Publicize With Hashtags](https://wordpress.org/plugins/publicize-with-hashtags/)), which does exactly that. It basically use and action trigger bound to the 'save_post' native event.

If you want to develop your own one you can have a look at my Source Code on the project's [GitHub page](https://github.com/Darkseal/publicize-with-hashtags) or in this [installation & usage guide](http://www.ryadel.com/en/add-hashtags-to-jetpack-publicize-shared-posts/) I wrote about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter, like so, to your theme's *functions.php* or a [site-specific plugin](http://yazminmedia.com/wordpress-blog/1-hour-wordpress-create-a-site-specific-plugin/):

```
add_filter( 'wpas_default_prefix', 'add_default_publicize_hashtag_prefix', 10, 4 );
function add_default_publicize_hashtag_prefix() {
    $default_tags = '#yourhastaghere ';
    return $default_tags;
}
```

This will add your default hashtag before your title without you needing to hack the WordPress core.

Comment: Technically he wouldn't be hacking the WordPress core, but rather a plugin file which would end up being overwritten during an update (same result as modifying core WP files though).

Answer (score 0):

`jetpack/modules/publicize/ui.php` itself states in its comments:

```
/**
* Only user facing pieces of Publicize are found here.
*/
```

You added your hashtag in the textarea which allows admins to enter a custom message (click edit and it will slide down with your hashtag).

As @Yazmin mentioned, the best way to permanently edit the message is using a filter. The filters available are `wpas_default_prefix`, `wpas_default_message`, and `wpas_default_suffix`.

Personally, [I had no success using these filters](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wpas_default_message-filter-not-working) and I'm interested in a working solution to this issue myself.